# Using jQuery to obtain (and change) the name of a checkbox field after it has been cloned?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some code which I am trying to modify so that a number within the name of a checkbox is obtained.

The objective is that after a few clicks the code becomes like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="UPDATE_METHOD[0][]" value="Email" checked="">Email
<input type="checkbox" name="UPDATE_METHOD[0][]" value="SMS" checked="">SMS

<input type="checkbox" name="UPDATE_METHOD[1][]" value="Email" checked="">Email
<input type="checkbox" name="UPDATE_METHOD[1][]" value="SMS" checked="">SMS

<input type="checkbox" name="UPDATE_METHOD[2][]" value="Email" checked="">Email
<input type="checkbox" name="UPDATE_METHOD[2][]" value="SMS" checked="">SMS
```

Current code is...

HTML:

```
   <div class="clone_replicate_this_div_1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="UPDATE_METHOD[0][]" value="Email" checked="">Email
        <input type="checkbox" name="UPDATE_METHOD[0][]" value="SMS" checked="">SMS
    </div>
        <div class="placer_1"></div>
        <a href="#" class="clone_trigger_button_1">Clone row 1</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".clone_trigger_button_1").click(function () {

                 // Group boxes in groups of 2
                var j = 0;

                $('[name="UPDATE_METHOD[0][]"]').prop('name', function(i, name) {
                    if (i%2==0) j++;
                    return name.split('[').shift() + '['+j+'][]';
                });

  $('.clone_replicate_this_div_1').last().clone().insertBefore(".placer_1");
                $('input.cl:last').val('');
                event.preventDefault();


      });
});
```

I'm trying to obtain the number of the last UPDATE_METHOD[0][], assign this as a variable, and then add 1.

A jsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/LCUTk/2/

Thanks for any help that you can give...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".clone_trigger_button_1").click(function () {
          var total = $('[name^="UPDATE_METHOD"]').length;
          var index = Math.round(total / 2);
          $('.clone_replicate_this_div_1').last().clone().insertBefore(".placer_1");
          $('input.cl:last').val('');
          $('.clone_replicate_this_div_1').last().find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("name","UPDATE_METHOD["+index+"][]");
          event.preventDefault();  
      });
});
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rynhe/LCUTk/3/)

Comment: Amazing!  This is great, thank so much :-)  This was the last part in fixing something I've been working on for a day!

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wLFFf/)

HTML:

```
<div class="placer_1"></div>
<a href="#" class="clone_trigger_button_1">Clone row 1</a>
<script type="text/template" id="template">
<div class="clone_replicate_this_div_1">
    <input class="email" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
    <label class="email_label">Email</label>
    <input class="sms"   type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
    <label class="sms_label">SMS</label>
</div>
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var html = $('#template').html(),
        placer = $( '.placer_1' ),
        index = 0,
        createInputs = function(){
            var div = $( html ),
                name = 'UPDATE_METHOD[' + index +  '][]';
            $( '.email', div ).attr( 'name', name )
                              .attr( 'id', 'update_method_email_' + index );
            $( '.sms',   div ).attr( 'name', name )
                              .attr( 'id', 'update_method_sms_' + index );
            $( '.email_label', div )
                              .attr( 'for', 'update_method_email_' + index );
            $( '.sms_label',   div )
                              .attr( 'id', 'update_method_sms_' + index );
            placer.before( div );
            ++index;
            console.log( index );
        };
    $(".clone_trigger_button_1").click(function ( evt ) {
        createInputs();
        evt.preventDefault();
    });
    createInputs();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is weird, but worked for me always.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var counter = 1 ;
$(".clone_trigger_button_1").click(function () {
    var newObject = '<div class="clone_replicate_this_div_1"><input type="checkbox" name="UPDATE_METHOD[' + counter + '][]" value="Email" checked="">Email<input type="checkbox" name="UPDATE_METHOD[' + counter + '][]" value="SMS" checked="">SMS</div>' ;
    $(newObject).insertBefore(".placer_1");
    counter++ ;
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```